# Most optimal way for element-wise multiplication of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array `f` of shape `(n,N)` and an array `w` of shape `(n,n)`. what is the fastest way to obtain an array `fw` of shape `(n,n,N)` whose elements are [image: f_ij w_il] where [image: i,l = \overline{0,n-1}] and [image: j=\overline{0,N-1}]. I see that this is similar to `np.tensordot` over the axes 0 and 0 but without actually summing in the end and contracting the dimensions. Also I would like to be generalizable to any dimensions i.e. to start with `A` of shape `(n_1,n_2,n_3,...)` and `B` of shape `(n_1,m_2,m_3,...)` and obtain from it an array
`AB` of shape `(n_1,n_2,..., m_2,m_3,...)`. I know one way would be to perform the outer product of `A` and `B` and then just select the elements where the [image: n_1] index is the same but I don't believe it is the most optimal way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 3d arrays, you can use [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to add another dimension to both arrays:

```
f = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
w = np.array([[7, 8], [9, 10]])
r = f[None, ...] * w[..., None]  
print(r) # [[[ 7, 14, 21], [32, 40, 48]], [[ 9, 18, 27], [40, 50, 60]]]
print(r.shape)  # (2, 2, 3)
```

I leave it to you to figure out if this works in the more general case and ask another question if not!